# How to preserve values between pages using knckout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am building a web app using ASP .NET MVC and Knockout by which a user can add/remove items from a shopping cart. There are only 2 pages, the homepage which shows special offers, and the second shows all offers so basically the model behind is exactly the same. In each page i can easily bind values to page controls so if user adds an item to cart other parts are automatically updated. My problem is that I lose the data when I change page. Is there anyway in knockout so I can keep these changes between pages. My best bet so far has been to store data on the server and retrieve it from server again when I go to a new page. Hope someone can help :)

Comment: It would be the best practice to store added item in your database whenever you add an item to your cat .You can use browser's cookies or local storage but they are not something you can rely on.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj Thanks for your reply. Yup, that has been my solution so far. I just wanted to be sure it's a good practice. And it seems it is since you mention it in your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to take @Matt.kaaj approach which is working perfectly now. I just quote it here:

> **It would be the best practice to store added item in your database whenever you add an item to your cat .You can use browser's cookies or
>   local storage but they are not something you can rely on. –
>   Matt.kaaj**